# How to get rid of border around and image used as a link in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Weird question I think its more of I am not sure what it is called. But I have an img wrapped in an link

example

```
...<li>
  <a href="#link">
    <img ...>
  </a>
 </li> .....
```

Now I have the css border rules all to 0. So their is no Blue border. But in Firefox their seems to be a pink mini dashed border only when I click on the image? In other browsers there is no border at any time. Im not sure if its from the browser itself or something I am missing. In my css I have border set to 0 on the a,:hover,:visited I even put text-decoration to none thinking that might help. But to know avail. I tried searching online for help but all I get is info on removing the border caused from placing the image in the link. So any help or a point in the right direction would be great. ! 
edit// I added a picture to better explain what I am talking about.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried what I just posted? I -guarantee- you it's the outline :)

Comment: yes I did try it and it was the outline. Thanks Marko!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Links (`<a>`’s) by default have a dotted outline around them when they become “active” or “focused”. In Firefox 3, the color is determined by the color of the text

To remove it, simply use:

```
a {
    outline: none;
}
```

Or you can do what I do, and remove it from all elements (I use my own focus/active rules) and do

```
* {
    outline: none;
}
```

This will remove it from all elements.

Comment: True. It will however affect usability and accessibilty. Keyboard navigation will be harder. The `outline` will namely be shown when you're tabbing through links. Rather consider giving it a less disturbing color using [`outline-color`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_outline-color.asp) property.

Comment: I agree, hence why I said using my own focus/active rules :) Outline isn't enabled by default in IE, so when tabbing through fields I change the background color or border color in the :active state.

Comment: Oh, that part of the answer wasn't there when I saw your answer for the first :)

Comment: Oh well that makes sense :) Thanks for the heads up anyway!

Comment: the outline:none; worked thanks thats what I was looking for. But I get what your saying Balus and I think I might just do it your way. On a side note. If I kept it at outline: none to the links with the imgs in it. Does tabbing through still go on through them but your just wont see it?

Comment: You just won't see them.. removing the outline property won't affect tabbing, you just won't know what element you're on. As mentioned above, you could use the a:active/a:focus state and set a different background image, text color, border or anything else that tickles your fancy :)

Comment: You might want to use a different background image with a slight different font color for `a:focus`.

Comment: Oh and @BalusC - thank you for assisting the answer, I would give you half the points if I could :)

Comment: Those are both great ideas! Thanks for the tip. But from what I though was that A:active is not used in firefox? Or am I thinking of something different?

Answer (score 0):

```
#link img a
{
border:0;
outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Install Firebug and see what's going on. I think what's going on is img tag probably has a default border.

To remove it maybe you can try putting your a and img tags inside of a div with an id and using following CSS:

Your HTML:

`<div id="test">
  <a...>
  <img .../>
  </a>
</div>`

And use the following CSS:

`#test img { 
  border-style: none; 
}`

Comment: Already got it working already but thanks. The borders were already set to 0 it was caused by the css property outline